# Do I need to explicitly DROP TABLE on temporary one?

Tags: sql, postgresql

As far as I understand, temp table exists only within connectivity session to database.
So, if my process closes connection every time after working with temp tables, technically I don't need to drop temp tables, correct?

I read that it's just a good practice to drop temp table before creation. Just in case I suppose. But there is no need for explicit DROP after I finished working with them, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are ending your session each time, there's no need to drop the table. However, I agree that it is good practice to drop it.

http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/statements/create_temporary_table

Answer (score 1):

as per manual(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptable.html)
You cannot `drop temp table`, you can only `drop table`.
Obviously you know whether you want to save the table or not.
If you don't want save the table. Then temp table will be dropped.
quoted from menu:

> If specified, the table is created as a temporary table. Temporary
> tables are automatically dropped at the **end of a session**, or
> optionally at the **end of the current transaction** (see ON COMMIT
> below). The default search_path includes the temporary schema first
> and so identically named existing permanent tables are not chosen for
> new plans while the temporary table exists, unless they are referenced
> with schema-qualified names. Any indexes created on a temporary table
> are automatically temporary as well.

Comment: my bad, I changed the title, I didn't mean DROP TEMP TABLE, I meant DROP TABLE on temporary table. Thanks